# How would a high fantasy medieval society react to an apocalypse caused by magic?

Tags: magic

Brief information about the setting. There was a big war going on between two countries. Let's call those countries A and B. Each living in different continents. While they were evenly matched A caught an advantage and pressed it and B out of desperation decided to cast a gigantic spell that would summon an army of demons against their enemies.

Long story short demons did destroy their enemies though the demons also destroyed their own army and now the continent the demons were summoned is now uninhabitable. How would the country A view magic after witnessing such destruction.

Note that magic is normally considered extremely critical both army wise and infrastructure wise.

Comment: They are all dead according to your post. No more views to be had. Or are we talking about the afterlife?

Comment: Sorry. The war is between two continents. I'll detail it.

Comment: This sounds like the magic equivalent of a nuclear apocalypse. It's safe to assume the same as we would regard nuclear energy & weapons after a nuclear war. Great but shouldn't be misused.

Comment: Do you have a preferred outcome? Because you can justify any reaction

Comment: @a4android: precisely. The OP simply has to look at the reaction to the bombs over Hiroshima and Nagasaki during WWII, followed by the bomb tests in the 50's and extrapolate.

Comment: @nzaman That's an excellent starting point. It's hard to grasp the full potential horror of a full-scale nuclear war. It's still closest thing to this demon apocalypse.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most fantasy worlds would call that "Tuesday Morning".

Comment: I think the OP needs to explain more about the magic in the proposed world. In particular, I would have thought, especially with magic being extensively used throughout the world, that there would be some differentiation between different types of magic. Summoning continent-destroying demons (does this mean demons cannot cross water?) does not seem quite the same as magic used to, for example, get clothes clean or stop the dog from running into the road.

Comment: @LeeLeon Unless there's only one spell in existence: to summon a demon to do your bidding. Someone just had the bright idea to command it to attack instead of walk the dog. :)

Comment: @Frostfyre - an interesting idea, I like the thought of a walk-the-dog demon! (Or a demon getting summoned and thinking, 'Oh No, not the ironing again! Surely they want to destroy something?')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fact that magic is critical to the army/society as a whole makes the question an interesting one.

Either A) society A decide that they were right to use this type of magic but obviously it must be tightly controlled and only used in the most severe circumstances etc

or B) they are horrified by the effects and outlaw all similar types of magic - think this one is interesting because you could end up with a witch hunt of people who use magic that is similar to the spell used but not harmful, and you could decide how arbitrary you want the laws to be.